# How to rotate image in java?

Tags: java

I'm new to java. I would like to load an image from file. Rotate it certain degrees and re wite it to a file and Not display onscreen.
But with a large number of classes in java, I don't know where to start.
Presently I know of loading and writing a buffered image.
Does anyone have any tutorials about rotation and saving without display ?
TIA

Comment: Duplicate question. Here is the correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4919880/1565832

Comment: You should be able to find tons of examples for this, if you google it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ImageIO` to read the image.

Use `AffineTransformOp` to rotate a `BufferedImage`.

Finally, write the image back, using `ImageIO`.

Answer (score 1):

```
AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
transform.rotate(radians, bufferedImage.getWidth()/2, bufferedImage.getHeight()/2);
AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(transform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
bufferedImage = op.filter(bufferedImage, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Image Magic java API to do all image manipulations you want to do. Here is the link http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jmagick/index.php?title=Main_Page