# Rotating an image in java awt

Tags: java, awt, java-2d

I have a game which runs in an applet. In there, there's a missile, which should point up, down, left or right. One way doing it would be creating 4 images (one for each direction), but that would be too complicated.

Does anyone know a way I rotate the image, once it's loaded into the program?

Comment: Please use the search function of StackOverflow

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918482/rotating-bufferedimage-instances

Comment: Here are several ways to rotate the Image:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918482/rotating-bufferedimage-instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this example using applet in java awt to rotate an image .

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.net.URL;

public class RotateImage extends Applet {

private Image image;

AffineTransform identity = new AffineTransform();

 private URL getURL(String filename) {
 URL url = null;
 try {
 url = this.getClass().getResource(filename);
 }
catch(Exception e){}
return url;
}

public void init() {
image = getImage(getCodeBase(), "image.jpg");
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
AffineTransform trans = new AffineTransform();
trans.setTransform(identity);
trans.rotate( Math.toRadians(45) );
g2d.drawImage(image, trans, this);
}
}
```

The most complicated part of the code is the AffineTransform object. According to Sun's AffineTransform API, "The AffineTransform class represents a 2D affine transform that performs a linear mapping from 2D coordinates to other 2D coordinates that preserves the "straightness" and "parallelness" of lines." If you experiment a little with this class (or just continue reading the API), you'll see that it can be used not just to rotate, but also to scale, flip, and shear an image as well.

Comment: ok , i will edit the answer according to your question

Comment: you can see the g.drawImage  at the end of the code

Comment: Umm... Why is getURL() there? I can't find any use for it in your code.