# storing transformed BufferedImage in Java

Tags: java, bufferedimage, affinetransform

In Java, instead of using photoshop to transform my images(that I use in the program), I want to use code to transform and save them.

I have created an AffineTransform object "at" and called the `rotate()` method. I have a BufferedImage called "image".

I can draw the image on the screen with the desired transformation with this code:

```
g2d.drawImage(image, at, null);
```

What I want to do is to store the combination of at and image in a new BufferedImage image2. How can I do this so that`g2d.drawImage(image2,50,50, null);` will show the rotated version of image?

edit: I've tweaked Ezequiel's answer a bit to get the effect I wanted.
    This did the trick:

```
BufferedImage image2= null;
AffineTransformOp affineTransformOp = new AffineTransformOp(at,AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
image2 = affineTransformOp.filter(image, image2);
g2d.drawImage(image2, 50, 50, null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`AffineTransformOp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/AffineTransformOp.html) class:

```
BufferedImage original; //Instatiate with desired image.
BufferedImage transformed:  //Used to store transformed image.
AffineTransform at; //Transformations needed.

AffineTransformOp affineTransformOp = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
affineTransformOp.filter(original, transformed );
```

Comment: This is probably what I need but I have some problems. If I initiate transformed image as null nothing happens and the screen is empty. If I initiate it with an image then the original image is on top of the chosen image of the transformed image.

Comment: I've fixed it by doing this:
`transformed = affineTransformOp.filter(original, transformed );` 

Thank you for the answer.