# Java: Rotation of a buffered image around its centre is skewed

Tags: java, rotation, bufferedimage

I am trying to rotate a buffered image in Java (a plane icon on the map) around its centre using help from here:
[Rotating BufferedImage instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918482/rotating-bufferedimage-instances)

When I use this code:

```
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

at.rotate(Math.toRadians(planeHeading),origImage.getWidth() / 2, origImage.getHeight() / 2);

AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

origImage = op.filter(origImage, null);

g.drawImage(origImage, x-origImage.getWidth() / 2, y-origImage.getHeight() / 2, null);
```

on rotation of 180-270 degree, the image is placed higher and a bit to the left of  its centre:

[image]

If I use this code:

```
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

at.translate(x, y);

at.rotate(Math.toRadians(planeHeading));

at.translate(-origImage.getWidth()/2, -origImage.getHeight()/2);

g.drawImage(origImage, at, null);
```

the image is rotated correctly, however the image itself gets very pixelated on its edges.

[image]

Can someone please help find the culprit?

This is the whole method:

```
@Override
public void paintWaypoint(Graphics2D g, JXMapViewer viewer, MapPlane w)
{
    g = (Graphics2D)g.create();

    try
    {
        origImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/map/mapPLANE.png"));

        Point2D point = viewer.getTileFactory().geoToPixel(w.getPosition(), viewer.getZoom());

        // Center coordinates
        int x = (int)point.getX();
        int y = (int)point.getY();

        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // Get heading of the plane and rotate the image
        String planeHeadingStr = w.getHeading();

        try
        {
            double planeHeading = Double.parseDouble(planeHeadingStr);

            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

            //Do the actual rotation
            at.rotate(Math.toRadians(planeHeading),origImage.getWidth() / 2, origImage.getHeight() / 2);
            AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
            origImage = op.filter(origImage, null);

            // Draw the image
            g.drawImage(origImage, x-origImage.getWidth() / 2, y-origImage.getHeight() / 2, null);

        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {

        }


        g.dispose();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.warn("couldn't read mapPLANE.png", ex);
    }

}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the same bilinear interpolation that you got for your `AffineTransformOp` in the second case where you draw directly using an `AffineTransform`, you should set another RenderingHint:

```
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, 
                   RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
```

Otherwise, in your case, it defaulted to NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR interpolation.

Comment: This is great. Thank you! And so I understand, what is the wrong in the first case? Best!

Comment: Hard to get my head around that (pun intended). Am I correct in assuming that the image is square?

Comment: It is. 40 pixels x 40 pixels.